# Is set $\{xy=1\}$ connected set in $4$-dim complex plane

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Is a set $\{xy=1\}$ is connected in $4$-dimensional complex plane (over real number set).

Comment: you mean $\{(t, 1/t)\}$ ...

Answer (score 1):

For any two points $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$ you can use the path $(x_1e^{it},ye^{-it})$ to connect $A$ to a point $C=(x_3,y_3)$ such that $\text{Arg}(x_3)=\text{Arg}(x_2)$, and therefore $\text{Arg}(y_3)=\text{Arg}(y_2)$. Then use the path $(x_3t,ty_3)$ to connect $C$ to $B$.